# Jquery/Ajax call with timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, timer, setinterval

I have a php page that echos out rows from a database. I want to call it via jquery/ajax every 30 seconds. But I also want to be able to call the page at any time so that if I add a record via the form, once the form submits I want the page via called to ajax to update the results right away. Can anyone point me in the right direction or provide some base code so I can try to figure this out? Still very new to jquery/ajax.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

If you want to set something on a timer, you can use JavaScript's `setTimeout` or `setInterval` methods:

```
setTimeout ( expression, timeout );
setInterval ( expression, interval );
```

Where `expression` is a function and `timeout` and `interval` are integers in milliseconds. `setTimeout` runs the timer once and runs the `expression` once whereas setInterval will run the `expression` every time the `interval` passes.

So in your case it would work something like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    //call $.ajax here
}, 5000); //5 seconds
```

As far as the Ajax goes, see jQuery's [`ajax()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). If you run an interval, there is nothing stopping you from calling the same `ajax()` from other places in your code.

---

If what you want is for an interval to run every 30 seconds until a user initiates a form submission...and then create a new interval after that, that is also possible:

`setInterval()` returns an integer which is the ID of the interval.

```
var id = setInterval(function() {
    //call $.ajax here
}, 30000); // 30 seconds
```

If you store that ID in a variable, you can then call `clearInterval(id)` which will stop the progression.

Then you can reinstantiate the `setInterval()` call after you've completed your ajax form submission.

Comment: Thanks for the response! So your saying if I use the code above to refresh the ajax call every 5 seconds then on the same page I have a form someone fills out that gets submit, once its done adding the record I can call the same setInterval function above and it wont have 2 instances of that function running at once?

Comment: So what you want is for an interval to run every 30 seconds *until* a user initiates a form submission...and then create a new interval after that? That is also possible. `setInterval()` returns an integer which is the ID of the interval. If you store that ID in a variable, you can then call `clearInterval(id)` which will stop the progression. Then you can reinstantiate the `setInterval()` call after you've completed your ajax form submission.