# Call jQuery Ajax Request Each X Minutes

Tags: ajax, jquery, timer

How can I call an *Ajax Request* in a specific period of time?
Should I use *Timer Plugin* or does *jQuery* have a plugin for this?

Comment: You can google this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542863/jquery-ajax-call-with-timer

Answer (score 146, accepted):

You can use the built-in javascript setInterval.

```
var ajax_call = function() {
  //your jQuery ajax code
};

var interval = 1000 * 60 * X; // where X is your every X minutes

setInterval(ajax_call, interval);
```

or if you are the more terse type ...

```
setInterval(function() {
  //your jQuery ajax code
}, 1000 * 60 * X); // where X is your every X minutes
```

Comment: only 2nd technique work

Answer (score 13):

A bit late but I used jQuery ajax method. But I did not want to send a request every second if I haven't got the response back from the last request, so I did this.

```
function request(){
            if(response == true){
                // This makes it unable to send a new request 
                // unless you get response from last request
                response = false;
                var req = $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url:"request-handler.php",
                    data:{data:"Hello World"}
                });

                req.done(function(){
                    console.log("Request successful!");

                    // This makes it able to send new request on the next interval
                    response = true;
                });
            }

            setTimeout(request(),1000);
        }

        request();
```

Comment: Why not just add `setTimeout(request(),1000);` inside the req.done and avoid the need to check the bool?

Comment: Well, good thinking. But the bool can be great for checking if the request has come forward anywhere else in the code. We say you can only click a submit button when the response has come back, then you can use that bool to check whether the response has come or not.

Answer (score 6):

you can use `setInterval()` in javascript

```
<script>
//Call the yourAjaxCall() function every 1000 millisecond
setInterval("yourAjaxCall()",1000);
function yourAjaxCall(){...}
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

No plugin required. You can use only jquery.

If you want to set something on a timer, you can use JavaScript's `setTimeout` or `setInterval` methods:

```
setTimeout ( expression, timeout );
setInterval ( expression, interval );
```

Comment: setinterval is actually from javascript not jquery.

Answer (score 4):

You have a couple options, you could `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()`.  [Here's a great article that elaborates on how to use them](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/).

The magic is that they're built in to JavaScript, you can use them with any library.

Answer (score 2):

use jquery [Every time Plugin](http://jquery.offput.ca/timers/)  .using this you can do ajax call for "X" time period

```
$("#select").everyTime(1000,function(i) {
//ajax call
}
```

you can also use **setInterval**

Comment: link is broken and what is the advantage of it, can't we just use setinterval instead?

Answer (score 1):

I found a very good jquery plugin that can ease your life with this type of operation. You can checkout https://github.com/ocombe/jQuery-keepAlive.

```
$.fn.keepAlive({url: 'your-route/filename', timer: 'time'},       function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      });//
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having an absolute repeating timer, you should call the function after completing the initial request (like a recursive function).

This ensures that requests will be **sent only after completing the previous one**. This avoids the issues like queuing up of requests and thereby Denial of Service.

```
(function ajaxRequest() {
  $.ajax('url_of_your_application.php', {
    type: 'post',
    data: {
      phone: '1234567890',
    },
  })
    .done(function (data) {
      // Do whatever you want with the data.
    })
    .always(function (data) {
      // We are starting a new timer only AFTER COMPLETING the previous request.
      setTimeout(ajaxRequest, 5000);
    });
})();
```