# How to check Every 30 minute if new data insert in db?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I want to reload my web page automatically if new row insert or delete any row or update.

I want to check  it every 30 munite.

if new if new row insert or delete any row or update then reload my website.

```
<ul>
    foreach($output['result'] as $key => $val) {

                print'<li data-artist="'.$val['artist'].'" data-title="'.$val['songName'].'" data-album="'.$val['songName'].'" data-info="" data-image="" data-duration="348">
                    <div class="amazingaudioplayer-source" data-src="http://somthing.info/'.$val['songUrl'].'" data-type="audio/mpeg" />
                </li>';         

    }
      </ul>
```

when any one first visit my website the i print data with this foreach.
if new if new row insert or delete any row or update then reload my website and my foreach retrieve data from database.

please help me how can i do this.

Comment: I may as well say it first. What have you tried so far.

Comment: Make an ajax request to php script every 30 minute. It is as simple as that

Comment: I can see that you've tagged this with ajax. That is correct. You'd use AJAX.

Comment: if your data is loaded using an ajax call. this can be easily done with the help of ajax. simply you need to send a ajax call every 30 mins.

Comment: web socket or long polling

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930439/call-jquery-ajax-request-each-x-minutes

Answer (score 2):

In the head you should define as following to refresh the page every 30 mins.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1800" />
</head>
```

but this is not the best way to do, you must use ajax. so something like this can be done easily.

```
setInterval(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: '/',
    type:"POST",
    data:"", 
    success: function(data){
      //render the dynamic data into html
    }
  });
}, 10000);
```

check this example to see how you can do the same with ajax. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_and_ajax.htm

Comment: It would not check for data modifications. Server side help is also required I believe.

Comment: yes i have updated the answer including an ajax example.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this using jquery

```
var seconds = 1800; //add your time interval here

setInterval(function(){
  $.ajax({
      url: 'url of file, which will check the update',
      data: 'pass any data or cache buster in case of proxy'
  });
}, seconds * 1000)
```

Answer (score -1):

Put a cron on your server to check if new data inserted in the database based on a previously saved db stat.

Comment: I do not think cron job will help here. He want to update page. Nothing sounds like cron job.