# Using Ajax to load and display external pages content every x minutes

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a php page and I want to use ajax or jquery to load a php page which is within the same file directory ever x minutes. the external php page I want to load every x minutes contains php code that queries a mysql database looking for new rows of data and if it finds one pops up a jquery module window with a form in it. My issue is all the same code I seem to find requires me to setup a div in the parent page and wants to load that content into just that div. However I want to display the external php page over the top of the entire page if that makes sense how I am explaining it.

My code I am trying to use but does not work is

```
setInterval(
  $.get( "checkapiinsert.php", function( data ) {
     $( "body" )
  },10000);
```

Comment: Basically I have a file that contains php and jquery and I want to keep reloading it every x number of minutes and display its result as if its part of the screen/file the user is currently on.

Comment: Duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930439/call-jquery-ajax-request-each-x-minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930439/call-jquery-ajax-request-each-x-minutes)

Comment: Thanks but that shows me a code that looks similar to what I have above. So how would I get my above code which is similar to the url you posted to actually work. I am given the code I have been told show work and its now working so I am coming to this site to ask for help to fix my code since it looks correct but it not working. I believe its the $( "body") part that is incorrect any suggestions on how to correct it. Again I want to code from the external page to not load in a specific div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close with your code.

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.get('checkapiinsert.php', function( data ) { 
       $('body').html(data);
    });
}, 5 * 1000 * 60);
```

Where `5 * 1000 (milliseconds) * 60 (seconds)` = 5 minutes

Though a better solution would be:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300;url=/checkapiinsert.php">
```

Assuming `checkapiinsert.php` is at your root.

Where `300` = 5 minutes

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refresh the whole page every 10000 miliseconds, why not use a meta tag or use javascript for a refresh

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">
```

Or use javascript

```
 setInterval(function(){location.reload(); },10000);
```