# How do you use a cron job to make a PHP script inside an HTML page repeat every minute?

Tags: php, html, cron

I have my HTML page with a few PHP scripts inside, I would like one of those scripts to repeat every minute. I created a new "minute.php" file and I would like to make it call the script every minute. I don't get in which file I have to put the script that I want to run every second, in the original HTML page or in the "minute.php" file. Where do I put the `* * * * * ...` line ?

Comment: You should put php file in cron as it will have logic. HTML file is just the output.

Comment: cron job depends on server you are using. this is for linux - http://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job

Answer (score 2):

If you are expecting the change in HTML after each minute use `setInterval` and not Cron Job.

[Call jQuery Ajax Request Each X Minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930439/call-jquery-ajax-request-each-x-minutes)

> You can use the built-in javascript setInterval.
>
> ```
> var ajax_call = function() {
>   //your jQuery ajax code
> };
>
> var interval = 1000 * 60 * X; // where X is your every X minutes
>
> setInterval(ajax_call, interval);
> ```
>
> or if you are the more terse type ...
>
> ```
> setInterval(function() {
>   //your jQuery ajax code
> }, 1000 * 60 * X); // where X is your every X minutes
> ```

`ajax_call` above can be ajax call to minute.php.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Do I put this script in the HTML file itself ?

Comment: @LeoFillioux yes, its a javascript, so yes in script tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could reside your `minute.php` script in any place you desire. Like `/var/www/site/cron/minute.php` for example.

To execute this script you may execute binary php program and pass it the path to the script as argument like the following:

```
$ /path/to/php /var/www/site/cron/minute.php
```

To run this command every minute you have to add the following record in `crontab`:

```
* * * * * /path/to/php /var/www/site/cron/minute.php
```

Note that the path to the script should be absolute.