# How to run a PHP function after specific time on server?

Tags: php

I have a function which adds a new blog post to my database.

After running ***add_new_post()*** function the post should be approved by my another function ***approve_post()***.

But I don't want to approve post immediately. I want to run ***approve_post()*** function in time between `1 to 5 minute (random)`.

Now I am using this code:

```
function add_new_post() {
    *my code of adding post*

    $time = rand(60, 300);
    echo $time;
    sleep($time);

    approve_post();
}
```

But browser shows loading until sleep ends. Also, I found that my Windows machine shows time execution error.

Is there a way to run `approve_post()` function in the background without showing page loading to the browser?

I would be grateful for а code example.

Comment: Add post and approve post should be two independent functions. `add_post()` should not even call `approve_post()`. Assuming `add_post()` is called when some button is pressed, create  another button for approving, and pass id of the post to the submit button. Mind that the `approve_post()` then must exect at least one parametr - some form of identification of the post. That pretty much is all advice i can give. It would take a lot more code to implement it.

Comment: Can't understand about what button you are talking about. It is automatic action of approving. I just want to run function,I don't need any buttons for approving post.

Comment: server side cron jobs

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options.

You can use ajax which is required to open a page or you can use a Cron job. I will prefer to use Cron job

The concept will same, for an example. The post table must has `created_date` ,`approve_date` and `approve_status`. So when you create the post it will save the `approve_date` too.

Example, You create a post on `18:00` then the `approve_time` will `18:05`. Then the background process (ajax or Cron job) will check the `approve_status` first then execute the `approve process` when live time same like `approve_time`

ref : [cron job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php) & [Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930439/call-jquery-ajax-request-each-x-minutes)

sorry for my English

Comment: Hm, AJAX is running on the client side. So, if user will close page this function will not execute. I need something server-side.

Comment: @NikolaiMaksimov then use cron_job, any reason why you want to `delay` the approve ?

Comment: The cron side is not clear for me. Do you have any examples based on my question? I have found only cron tasks to do something at specific time, for example each hour. But my time is being specified when **add_new_post()** function runs.

Comment: Ajax are is out of the question. Server side solution lies in php, the correct organization of the form and correct usage of form. Cron... is not a great solution in general, because it removes the ability to revew the post before accepting them

Comment: I don't want my users to know that posts are being approved by function, not by real person. So, different delay time adds human-like behavior.

Comment: Well then independant script for accepting posts and a cronJob is the answer. `approve_post()` should not be called from `add_post()` if you don't want to delay the execution of `add_post()`

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin can you please give some code examples or link it it is possible? I can't understand how to fit cron here.

Comment: @Nikolai Maksimov See answer below, links are there.

Comment: just run the cron every minute to run a file that checking the post table. if the criteria true, you can run approve query.

Comment: @MyNameIs I found out that cron is limited to minimum 1 minute of delay. Don't you know any ways to leverage time? It is just for knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to increase  the [maximum execution](https://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/max-ex.php) time of a PHP script by using the following link https://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/max-ex.php

Then use `sleep()` function to delay code execution as:

```
<?php
echo date('H:i:s');
sleep(15);
flush();
echo "<br>";
echo date('H:i:s');
?>
```

[Reference link](https://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/sleep.php)

Or you can [CronJob](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/run-function-every-night/43898/5)

Comment: `sleep()` is new thing for me . what if user closing the browser ?

Comment: Yes, for that cronJob is the best option

Comment: Hasan, sleep function doesn't fit my requirements. But cron seems to fit. I need to create new cron task each time user adding post?