# DB Work on Timer Tick Event and displaying result on page ever x Seconds

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, razor, timer

I am working on a Timer control for my website, and the page my have up to 100 timers on it. Each timer needs to have a Tick event that POSTs to a *.cshtml page to do some DB work and retrieve some info to be displayed beneath the timer on the page.

I really didn't want to ask this question but I'm afraid I have to, I have been at this for weeks and just don't know how to go about it. I have looked up several timers on Google but haven't found anything that was of any help in this situation.

I'd really appreciate any help at all.

Thank you

Comment: JQuery AJAX and setInterval... http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542863/jquery-ajax-call-with-timer

Comment: Thank you @Lloyd. Is there by any chance a way to change the maximum time for a timer that is already running? I tried it in jquery, but unsuccessfully.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280263/changing-the-interval-of-setinterval-while-its-running    http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp