# How to show other users activity count on site (browser) title that refreshes automatically in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

How can I show a users' activity count on site title that refreshes automatically like 
Facebook, LinkedIn, StackOverflow etc.

e.g. in linkedIn I usually see following title on browser to indicate one new activity updated on linkedIn wall.

```
(1) Imran Rizvi | Linkedin
```

I was searching for this question but did not find any solution.

I would if appreciate if anybody could let me know how to do this and with best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use timer like control which calls a javascript function after a fixed interval like javascript setInterval. In this function you have to send ajax call and get the updates and render the updates with javascript

Here is similar question [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542863/jquery-ajax-call-with-timer)

Here is similar functionality could be achieved asp.net ajax toolkit timer control [Timer ajax control](http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/timer-control/)

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Timer runat="server" ID="Timer1" Interval="5000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
            </asp:Timer>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

 protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     //refresh page title
     Page.Title = "Title refreshed: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the idea. I think implementing this through web service would be good practice as it will not need to partial post back and run the whole page life cycle.