# How to keep on calling Jquery on Success

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call the webservice until i get the desired Output.
This is the code i am using.

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
        url: "../WebService/myservice.asmx/GetStatus",
        data: "{'myparameter': '" + value + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
                 return response.d;
                 },
        error: function (x, e) {
                alert("The call to the server side failed. " + x.responseText);
                }
});
```

This webservice will return me the result. i want that until the result is completed the jquery call should execute every 1 sec.

Comment: Do you want to call webservice each 1 sec and show success result?

Comment: Check Deferred Object in jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [good start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542863/jquery-ajax-call-with-timer)

The idea is to encapsulate your code into a method and then call it using [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval):

```
setInterval(ajaxCall, 1000);
```

For example:

```
function ajaxCall(){
  $.ajax(
  {
      type: "POST",
          url: "../WebService/myservice.asmx/GetStatus",
          data: "{'myparameter': '" + value + "'}",
          contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          async: true,
          cache: false,
          success: function (response) {
                   return response.d;
                   setInterval(ajaxCall, 1000); //call itself
                   },
          error: function (x, e) {
                  alert("The call to the server side failed. " + x.responseText);
                  setInterval(ajaxCall, 1000); //try again
                  }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function ajaxCall() {
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function (response) {
            //got desired output?
            /*logic*/
            //no?
            setTimeOut(ajaxCall, 1000);
        },
        error: function() {
            setTimeOut(ajaxCall, 1000);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A variant using jQuery's `Deferred`/`promise` mechanism:

```
// interval in ms, use retries = 0 for unlimited retries
function poll(url, data, interval, retries) {
    var result = $.Deferred(), retryCount = 0;

    (function repeat() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/json; Charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            cache: false
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            if (response.d === "success") {
                result.resolve(response);
            }
        })
        .fail(function (x, e) {
            if (retries === ++retryCount) {
                result.reject("Maximum number of retries reached (" + url + ")");
            } else {
                setTimeout(repeat, interval);
            }
        });
    })();

    return result.promise();
}
```

Usage:

```
poll(
    "../WebService/myservice.asmx/GetStatus",
    {myparameter: value}, 1000, 100
)
.then(function (response) {
    // ...
})
.fail(function (error) {
    alert(error);
    // ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your ajax-request in a named function, that you can call whenever you need to make another request. In the success-callback you check the result, and if you aren't happy with it, set a timeout to call the function again in one second.

Something like this:

```
(function Fetch (){
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../WebService/myservice.asmx/GetStatus",
        data: "{'myparameter': '" + value + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response != "completed") {
                setTimeout(Fetch, 1000);
            } else {
                // Do something when completed 
            }
        },
        error: function (x, e) {
            alert("The call to the server side failed. " + x.responseText);
        }
   });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

As the earlier comments explained, if you wanted it to call every second (or period of time). you can use either `setTimeout()`(inside the function) or `setInterval()`(outside). But if you wanted to keep trying just until you got the desired code, you better use looping inside the function:

```
function startRequest() {
    while(1){
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
                url: "../WebService/myservice.asmx/GetStatus",
                data: "{'myparameter': '" + value + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                success: function (response) {
                         return response.d;
                         i=0;
                         break;
                         },
                error: function (x, e) {
                        alert("The call to the server side failed. " + x.responseText);
                        }
        });
    }
}
```