# Update listbox on time asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql, sql-server

I have a listbox that is getting data from the database . My problem is that i want to refresh that list box on every 3 seconds for example or some n seconds. Is this possible in ASP.Net can i update listbox on time without refreshing whole page? and if it is possible how can i do it?

Ok i did research about the updatepanel but i have problem making datasource of listbox and listbox refresh .

Thanks.

Comment: Research the use of a timer inside an updatepanel

Comment: and here's the link: [Tutorial: How to refresh an UpdatePanel control at a timed interval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295400(v=expression.40).aspx)

Comment: You could use a timer coupled with an ajax call. See this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4542863 .

Comment: Tim thanks for link but how can i refresh listbox with data source? i don't see example here

Comment: I tried with dataSource.update() option and i setted the UpdateCommand to same as the initialization one. And then referenced data source of new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think $.ajax should works great to you along with JavaScript setInterval like:

```
<script>
YourMethodName();

function YourMethodName()
{
  //bind your listbox using $.ajax
  setInterval(YourMethodName, 3000);
}
</script>
```

If you nee help how to bind listbox using jQuery then http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=454 may help you.