# creating auto destroy function in php

Tags: php

I am creating a functionality called tentative booking.

When a user books a ticket, he is given a temporary pnr-number and he should be given about 10 minutes to perform his payment.

If he fails to pay within 10 minutes, the transaction should be cancelled. Otherwise a success-message should be displayed.

Please ignore the logic for the payment. It can be any method.

I'm generating the temporary pnr-number and storing it into the database.

I can't understand how should I proceed here.

Is there any functionality in php which I can use for this?

Here is my code :

```
    $pnr = getPnr();
        echo "You temporarary pnr num is : $pnr <br>";
    echo "Check you mail and save it for future use";
    if($book_ticket == 'true')
    {       DoTentativeBooking($userid,$book_ticket,$from,$to,$date,$pnr,$seats,$email);

    }
function DoTentativeBooking($userid,$book_ticket,$from,$to,$date,$pnr,$seats,$email)
{
        $con = mysqli_connect('server', 'user', 'password', 'database');                
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            return;
        }
        $insertQuery1 = "INSERT INTO tbl_user(`user_id`,`book_ticket`,`from`,`to`,`date`,`user_pnr`,`seat`,`email`,`isConfirm`) VALUES ('".$userid."','".$book_ticket."','".$from."','".$to."','".$date."','".$pnr."','".$seats."','".$email."','No')";
        if (!mysqli_query($con,$insertQuery1))
            {
            //  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
                echo "error";
            }       
        return; 
}
```

Comment: I hope none of parameters of `DoTentativeBooking` directly come from `$_GET` or `$_POST`, because your query seem vunerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @AntonioRagagnin if `$_GET or $_POST` can't be used than how to get data??

Comment: It can be used, but you're injecting your data directly into your query string, use MySQL parameters instead.

Comment: You should really change your database credentials, as you have published them in your question!!!

Comment: server or client side?
client side js+ajax
server side background php or sql job

Comment: I suggest you tu use `prepared-statements` to perform queries: http://it1.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Comment: @NishantSolanki, maybe I didn't used right technical language, I meant, I hope the author didn't used something like `$user=$_GET['user']`. A solution would be `$user=mysql_escape_string ($_GET['user'])`

Comment: @AntonioRagagnin mysql_escape_string isn't safe ad it's deprecated

Comment: @AntonioRagagnin @VeNoMiS ... i would say `$_GET` isnt safe either.. for this type of apps `session and post variables` are best.. :P

Comment: @VeNoMiS: mysqli_escape_string(), any issue with this? I have still not switched to pdo

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can try this...

set a `time variable` while you are setting `temporary pnr number`..

```
$date = new DateTime();
$time1 = $date->getTimestamp(); // this will give you current timestamp..
```

and put a checking condition in header like..

```
$time2 = $date->getTimestamp();
if(round(abs($time1 - $time2) / 60,2) >= 10)
{
   unset($pnr);
}
```

Comment: What happens if they start at 1:56 then don't go to the checkout page until 2:24? Your value would be -32 and it wouldn't be kicked out.

Comment: -32 is not less than -50 your edit doesn't make it any better.

Comment: You need to use a complete timestamp and calculate the number of seconds (and convert it to minutes if needed) as @deceze has recommended above.

Comment: @Pitchinnate yeah you are right.. let me edit my answer.. Thanks btw :)

Comment: @NishantSolanki How can set condition which keep checking timestamp exiperation?

Comment: @cyclic I will suggest you to use javascript and ajax... call one ajax file every minute(or whatever you want) using `javascript's timer() function..`

Comment: @cyclic this will help you out... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542863/jquery-ajax-call-with-timer...

Answer (score 3):

1. Save a timestamp of when the order was created and/or when it expires together with the order in the database.
2. Set some flag that you're awaiting payment, e.g. set the `status` column to "awaiting_payment" or whatever, in the database.
3. Whenever handling any orders, filter them by their status flag/handle them accordingly.
4. On the payment confirmation page, when flipping the status to "paid", check the expiration timestamp.

In other words, you're not doing anything at a specific time or are expiring anything at a specific time. You simply save enough information that lets you figure out at any time when you need it what the status of the order is.

Comment: this logic I understand, i am facing probelm how to give time of 10 minutes. Any php code snippet will help me more

Comment: What's the exact problem? Creating a timestamp 10 minutes in the future? Checking if the current time is before or after a timestamp?

Comment: yes, waiting for 10 minutes for some action. If that does not occur withing stipulated time, so transaction failed

Comment: So, what is the concrete problem? Saving the timestamp into the database when you insert the order? Comparing the saved timestamp to the current time when you're about to accept or reject the payment?

Comment: Do i need to save it in db? I am not sure. Consider checking `isPaymentCompleted` variable in database after 10 minutes, if this is set to no, then display error message

Comment: I saved in database, but now do I need to check it continously? how to do it

Comment: You have obviously *not* understood the logic. Please try to read the individual rules I wrote again one by one.