# How to add the SQL Server data to each interval

Tags: c#, sql-server, timer, setinterval

I have this code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=SYNCLAPN136;Initial Catalog=Testdata;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
con.Open();

string command = "INSERT INTO [Table_1] (xName, yName) VALUES(@x, @y)";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@x", date);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@y", val);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();

return date;
```

Those date and values are generated randomly..

I need to add the data to each 30 sec... how to achieve this?

Comment: Add the data in a loop or add 30 seconds to each?

Comment: @JeremyThompson yes need to add each every 30 seconds(like setInterval)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to just run this code every 30 seconds you can use a Timer object , this code must solve for you :

```
private static System.Timers.Timer t;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        t = new System.Timers.Timer(new TimeSpan(0,0,0,30).TotalMilliseconds);
        t.Start();

    }


    public static void ExecuteSql()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
        {
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=SYNCLAPN136;Initial Catalog=Testdata;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
            con.Open();

            string command = "INSERT INTO [Table_1] (xName,yName) VALUES(@x,@y)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@x", date);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@y", val);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

If the contents of the variables esteam in windows controls, this will be a problem , there will need access to otherwise these values.

Comment: Hi Thanks for u r solution but in my scenario i have using ajax in client side,

  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../../web/WebForm1.aspx/LiveData",
        data: JSON.stringify({ "date": dateVal, "val": rn }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('success', data);

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Exeption:' + errorThrown);
        }
    });

so i need to generate in LiveData()

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ajax then use setInterval

```
setInterval(function(){ $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "../../web/WebForm1.aspx/LiveData", data: JSON.stringify({ "date": dateVal, "val": rn }), contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: 'json', success: function (data) { console.log('success', data); }, error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert('Exeption:' + errorThrown); } }); }, 30000);
```

Refer the post here [Jquery/Ajax call with timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542863/jquery-ajax-call-with-timer)

Comment: my requirement is when i click the button in client side i have use ajax method and in code behind need to iterate in server