# how to change data in gridview without reloading page asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, gridview, webgrid

I am new in asp.net mvc .I want to fetch the values of the webgrid in textbox along with this i want to change the values of text box without reloading the page thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [AJAX with Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542863/jquery-ajax-call-with-timer). or for realtime updates you can use [SignalR](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/signalr)

To know more about signalR [this an example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJLXS1H3eAM)